# get values from table with BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a table where I am extracting links and text. Although I can only do one or the other. Any idea how to get both?

Essentially I need to pull the text: "TEXT TO EXTRACT HERE"

```
 for tr in rows:
                    cols = tr.findAll('td')
                    count = len(cols)
                    if len(cols) >1:

                        third_column = tr.findAll('td')[2].contents
                        third_column_text = str(third_column)
                        third_columnSoup = BeautifulSoup(third_column_text)

#issue starts here. How can I get either the text of the elm <td>text here</td> or the href text<a href="somewhere.html">text here</a>
                        for elm in third_columnSoup.findAll("a"):
                            #print elm.text, third_columnSoup
                            item = { "code": random.upper(),
                                        "name": elm.text }
                            items.insert(item )
```

The HTML Code is the following

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="ListResults">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="even">
            <td colspan="4">sort results: <a href=
            "/~/search/af.aspx?some=LOL&amp;Category=All&amp;Page=0&amp;string=&amp;s=a"
            rel="nofollow" title=
            "sort results in alphabetical order">alphabetical</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>rank</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/as.asp#Rank">?</a></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
            <th>aaa</th>

            <th>vvv.</th>

            <th>gdfgd</th>

            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="odd">
            <td align="right" width="32">******</td>

            <td nowrap width="60"><a href="/aaa.html" title=
            "More info and direct link for this meaning...">AAA</a></td>

            <td>TEXT TO EXTRACT HERE</td>

            <td width="24"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="even">
            <td align="right" width="32">******</td>

            <td nowrap width="60"><a href="/someLink.html"
            title="More info and direct link for this meaning...">AAA</a></td>

            <td><a href=
            "http://www.fdssfdfdsa.com/aaa">TEXT TO EXTRACT HERE</a></td>

            <td width="24">
                <a href=
                "/~/search/google.aspx?q=lhfjl&amp;f=a&amp;cx=partner-pub-2259206618774155:1712475319&amp;cof=FORID:10&amp;ie=UTF-8"><img border="0"
                height="21" src="/~/st/i/find2.gif" width="21"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td width="24"></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="4" style="padding-top:6pt">
            <b>Note:</b> We have 5575 other definitions for <strong><a href=
            "http://www.ddfsadfsa.com/aaa.html">aaa</a></strong> in our
            database</td>
        </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you post the whole html (or the relevant part) you are parsing?

Comment: hey @alecxe I have updated the code. Many Tks.

Comment: This might help you! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817184/beautifulsoup-get-value-in-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the `text` property on a `td` element:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """HERE GOES THE HTML"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    columns = tr.find_all('td')
    if len(columns) > 2:
        print columns[2].text
```

prints:

```
TEXT TO EXTRACT HERE
TEXT TO EXTRACT HERE
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I get an error when doing print third_column.text
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: Actually, if I do the following it works third_column_text = str(third_column)
                        third_columnSoup = BeautifulSoup(third_column_text)
                        if third_columnSoup:
                            print third_columnSoup.text

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is by doing the following:

third_column = tr.find_all('td')[2].contents

```
                third_column_text = str(third_column)
                third_columnSoup = BeautifulSoup(third_column_text)
                if third_columnSoup:
                    print third_columnSoup.text
```